# Adding a existing file to a project using visual studio command lines

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, command-line, visual-studio-extensions

I'm writing an visual studio extension and I'm creating a read me file that I want to add to the c# project. I'm running this visual studio commands

```
var dte = (DTE2)ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE));
var tsFile = @"C:\Users\devVictorC\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\Readme.txt";
dte.ExecuteCommand("File.AddExistingItem", tsFile);
```

but I get this exception

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need add file to `.csproj` you can try this code:

```
var dte = (DTE2)ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE));
var tsFile = filePath;
dte.ItemOperations.AddExistingItem(tsFile);
```

Also see MSDN documentation: [ItemOperations.AddExistingItem Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.itemoperations.addexistingitem(v=vs.140).aspx)

Comment: Thank you. Now, doesn't even compile because GlobalProvider is missing some references or doesn't exist. any advice?

Comment: @VictorAChavez do I understand correctly that you are using Visual Studio 2017? If it so, is the reference to the library Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0 added to the project?